# Swipe to cancel / dismiss screen Android

Tags: android

I need to make a custom swipe to cancel/dismiss screen (like an alarm) to notify the users that it's time for a meeting and stuff like that (with sound and vibration).

Is there a way to use the default alarm (clock) screen but changing/adding texts or images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Comment: ive made my research over stackoverflow and the web but i dont find any solution, i will edit my post with the links where i have searched, i don´t have any code yet because i didnt want to waste time creating a complete activity if i could edit the default alarm screen

Answer (score 0):

For this you need a swipe gesture detection feature. Just detect the swipe gesture e.g right to left and perform a specific task. Some open source libraries are also available to achieve this goal. Check this,

[Gesticulate - Android swipe detection made simple](https://github.com/aglover/gesticulate)